# Inverse function table

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, inverse

[image]

I am required to create a table of values (like the one above) for h<sup>-1</sup>(x).

Because x is ordered, i am just wondering, would the two tables would be identical? I just feel a little insulted that's all.

Comment: I suspect you are expected to move the bottom row up and then reorder the columns

Comment: Correct @Henry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well yeah. The values would be just exactly the same and the tables would be identical, because that table shows the domain and range values. For the inverse, the domain and range are just swapped.

Comment: Thought so, thanks. Marking as correct in 10 min.